# push notification doesn't show up on status bar

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin

i'm using phonegap with phonegap-plugin-push , and i tried the example that comes with the plugin , i tested it on my phone ( Galaxy s4 , Android 5.0.1 ) , when i send notification while application is on i got vibration and the message is showing inside the cards div as mentioned in index.js but i got no notification on status bar , if the application is on background i got also no notification on status bar but i got vibration. i wonder why i have no notification popup on status bar.
i use phonegap-plugin-push 1.4.4

Comment: Can you give the call that you are sending? I am using it right now and works well.

Answer (score 1):

@Del

i am using ruby to send a notification

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pushmeup'

GCM.host = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send'
GCM.format = :json
GCM.key = "key"
destination = ["id"]
data = {:title => "PhoneGap Push",:message => "PhoneGap Build rocks!",         :msgcnt => "1", :soundname => "beep.wav"}
options = {:collapse_key => "placar_score_global", :time_to_live => 3600, :delay_while_idle => false}

GCM.send_notification( destination, data, options)
```

Comment: i got it solved , i added an icon : it has to be in the root of my phonegap project and it's done.

Comment: Anass Boukalane - can you give the sample code. i am also face same issue

Comment: @ Prithvi Raj Nandiwal you have to add icon option in the the ruby code above in order to make it apear

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the push notification you will also want to raise a local notification at that point which will appear in your status bar and notification tray. I'm a fan of the `phonegap-plugin-localNotifications` plugin for doing this, you can find it at https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-localNotifications. So in your phonegap-plugin-push onNotification handler for Android you would do something like this:

```
onNotification: function (e) {
    if (e.event == "message") {
        localNotification.add(1, {
            message: e.payload.message,
            badge: 1
        });
    }
}
```